# ¿Por qué tengo el error "[: ==: unary operator expected" en Bash?

Tags: bash, comparaciones

Intento hacer un peque;o script para levantar unos servicios automáticamente, pero a la hora de correrlo me marca este error.

> ```
> [: ==: unary operator expected
> ```

Mi código es:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIA=`date +”%d/%m/%Y”`
HORA=`date +”%H:%M”`
OPENVPN=`ps aux | grep 'openvpn' |grep -v grep|wc -l`
if [ $OPENVPN == 0 ]; then
   /sbin/openvpn --cd /etc/openvpn --config openvpn.cfg --script-security 2 --daemon
   echo -e "\n Se ha levantado el proceso"
   read -n 1 -s -r -p "Presione una tecla para continuar"
else
   echo "El Servicio esta Online"
fi
echo "Agregando ruteo al 1.80"
route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 gw 10.10.1.1 tap0
echo "pingeando al 1.80"
ping -c 10 192.168.1.80`
```

¿A qué se debe este error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

prueba el if con doble corchete `if [[ $OPENVPN == 0 ]];`, con el simple corchete si la variable no está entrecomillada desaparece onda

```
if [ "$OPENVPN" = 0 ];
```

vale como comparación, en cambio si `$OPENVPN` está vacío

```
[ $OPENVPN == 0 ]
```

se transforma en

```
[ == 0 ]
```

y te salta ese error

Comment: Muchas gracias! ha quedado, llevo varios dias sin dormir por la universidad y el trabajo. creo que necesito un descanzo

Comment: Correcto. De todos modos, `[[ ]]` es solo válido en Bash, por lo que si el script se intenta correr en, por ejemplo, Shell, no valdrá. Mejor entrecomillar siempre y usar `[ ]`.

Comment: Funciona el doble corchete ;) muchas gracias