# Me sale el error [: -lt: unary operator expected y no entiendo por que

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Es una tabla de multiplicar que va para atras y tienes que poner tres variables:

la tabla de multiplicar y desde (p1 * p2) hasta (p1 * p3)

ejemplo:

```
./tabla 7 (tabla del 7) 5 (donde empezara) 2 (donde acabara)
./tabla 7 5 2
```

Mi código es este:

```
cont=$p2
while [ $p1 -lt $cont ]
do
    resp=$(($1*$cont))
    echo "$1 x $cont = $resp"
    ((cont--))
done
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué tengo el error "\[: ==: unary operator expected" en Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176071/por-qu%c3%a9-tengo-el-error-unary-operator-expected-en-bash)

Answer (score 1):

Estás comparando variables que no existen, luego la línea

```
while [ $p1 -lt $cont ]
```

Bash la interpreta como

```
while [ -lt $p2]
```

es decir, falta el valor a la izquierda.

Para evitar este error, primero inicializa bien la variable. Después, usa comillas dobles para que no quede vacío uno de los lados de la comparación:

```
while [ "$p1" -lt "$cont" ]
```

Comment: Me sigue saliendo error ahora algo de integer

Comment: deberías pegar tu código en https://www.shellcheck.net pues hay errores de base importantes

Comment: Ahora me dice que nos esta asignada y es eso lo que no veo.

Comment: @lethal_shooter si quieres coger el primer parámetro que te pasan al ejecutar el script debes decir `p1=$1`

Answer (score 1):

¿Por qué te marca el error? Como lo menciono @fedorqui estas accediendo a la variable `$p1` que representa tu tabla a generar de forma erronea, debes acceder a la variable `$1` y definirla entre comillas a eso **se le conoce como sustitución de variables** y se define `while [ "$3" -lt "$cont" ]`
. 
Las comillas haran que se sutituyan las variables por su valor respectivo.

Pero tu lógica no esta del todo bien ya que la variable que debes utilizar en el lugar de dicha variable es `$3` la cual contiene el límite de tu tabla a generarse.

Por lo que tu código queda de la siguiente manera:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cont=$2
while [ "$3" -lt "$cont" ]
do
    resp=$(( $1*$cont ))
    echo "$1 x $cont = $resp"
    let cont-=1
done
```

Para la ejecución `./tabla 7 5 2` el programa devolverá:

```
7 x 5 = 35
7 x 4 = 28
7 x 3 = 21
```

Técnicamente `let cont-=1` y `((cont--))` son equivalentes. El programa sufre sustancialmente la adecuación de las variables correctas a la hora de comparar en el **while** y el acceso correcto a las variables $1, $2 y $3 que son los párametros pasados en la terminal `$1 = 7`, `$2 = 5` y `$3 = 2`. Saludos!