# Error en if " [: ==: unary operator expected"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, git-bash

Estoy recién utilizando termux y estoy creando un script:

```
clear 
echo -e -n " >>> "
function comandos() {
clear
if [ $inputr == "Ss." ]; then
echo "Fail"
else
echo "del"
fi
read -r inputr
comandos
}
comandos
```

Y obtengo este error:

```
Error: line 3: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

Estoy tratando de hacer que el `read` sea infinito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sobre ese error, hay respuestas dentro del sitio que te podrían ayudar. Por ejemplo, [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176071/por-qu%C3%A9-tengo-el-error-unary-operator-expected-en-bash).

### Respuesta corta

Mueve la sentencia `read -r inputr` hasta antes del `if` dentro de la función `comandos`:

```
...
clear
read -r inputr  # Aquí
if [ $inputr == "Ss." ]; then
...
```

### Respuesta larga

Este error te sucede porque dentro del [builtin `[`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins), durante la primera pasada, el valor de la variable `inputr` es vacio, quedando algo así: `[ == "Ss." ]`, es decir, son **dos argumentos** (esto será importante para entender el error).

Esto no tiene sentido para bash, puesto que el builtin `[`, **con los dos argumentos**:

1. Sólo acepta operadores unarios como `-a`, `-x`, etc., seguidas de una cadena como `-a archivo`,
2. El carcater `!` como negación.

Si no contiene alguna de estas, dara error.

Por otro lado, tu script se ve un tanto raro. Te propongo un cambio de esta manera:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare _prompt=">>>"

comandos() {
    read -p "$_prompt " inputr
    clear
    if [ "$inputr" = "Ss." ]; then
        echo "Fail"
    else
        echo "del"
    fi
}

while :
do
    comandos
done
```

### Recomendación

Sé que scriptear en termux ha de ser lindo porque te luces con los amigos y frente a ti mismo, pero también sé que es muy incómodo con el teclado que te proporciona.

Si no quieres andar de farolón y sólo te quieres centrar en el script dentro de tu ambiente creado por termux, te sugiero que te conectes via `ssh`.

Instalas openssh server en termux (creo que usa `pkg`), y desde tu computadora personal (la que si tiene teclas) te conectas a tu termux con un cliente de ssh hacía el puerto 8082 (creo):

```
tu computadora personal$ ssh <usuario>@<la ip de tu celular> -p 8022
```

Me parece que el usuario por defecto es algo como `u0_<y otra cosa>`, y creo que, con la cuestión de la contraseña, tendrás que hacer una autenticación por clave pública. Creo que no se puede editar el archivo `/etc/ssh/sshd` para poder hacer todo tipo de porquerías inseguras, y esto debido a un tema de los permisos.

También puedes ver tu ip local creo que con `ip addr` dentro de `termux`. No recuerdo si se puede hacer algo como `hostname -I` o `ifconfig` para ver tu ip local. O, si no puedes, utiliza `nmap` desde alguna otra computadora en tu red o ver si tu router es accesible desde `192.168.1.254` y ver si en el panel puedes ver los dispositivos conectados. Todo esto pensando que estás dentro de la misma red.